# Drupal page navigation with tab index for accessibility

Tags: navigation

I am tasked with the problem of making sure, that the page can be navigated by keyboard - mainly using the tab-key. I was wondering if there is a module or a certain way in Drupal to archive this since using JS to set the tabindex seems to be a very ugly solution which potentially could create chaos and slow down the page immensely.

Any hints or pointers are more than welcome.

Comment: Using JavaScript wouldn't help with making the page accessible either...what elements do you specifically need to add a tab index to, and where/how are those elements generated?

Comment: Basically the page is divided into four blocks. The menu and it's submenu (standard drupal menu), a content block (may contain links), a gallery (not important now) and another block with links in it. I need to jump through the menu, into the content block, to the block with the link in it. Can you elaborate how JS won't help? I was thinking about adding the tabindex-attribute with it.

Comment: A fair proportion of people who need to make use of accessibility features won't have javascript available, so you'd be kind of fixing a problem for people who don't really need it while missing a lot of those who really do. Presumably you're doing this for some sort of section 508/DDA compliance, so it's probably not worth implementing half-measures. I'd recommend identifying the elements you need to add the attribute to, then working out how to alter each using theme hooks

Comment: Didn't think about JavaScript not being available ;) But that is true. Alright, I'll reconsider my approach. Hooks seems to be the best way to do it. Thank you!